# How to implement a SQL-Server IBotDataStore in botframework

Tags: botframework

Does anybody have an example of how to implement a SQL-Server IBotDataStore and set it to be used on a botframework application?

If possible please provide us the database schema used on the implementation ?

Thnks

Comment: This is way too broad to be asked here. This is also not a code-writing service. You need to have provided your attempt in order to ask a question here.

Comment: This is NOT to broad to asked here. According to the botframework documentation, you just need to implement IBotDataStore interface. However it provides any details about the relationship between the data that the methods explosed by this interface has in order to help the implementor create a right implementation.

Comment: You're asking someone to provide you with the database schema they used to implement this and you're going to tell me it isn't too broad? I've seen all sorts of questions like this get closed. Questions asking for examples always get closed under too broad.

Comment: Take the LoadAsync method for example...
It takes an 'IAddress' and a 'BotStoreType' as input parameters. 
But to implement the method you need to know exactly by witch fields of the address you have to filter the data depending on the botStoreType value you receive. I have no Idea and the documentation tells nothig

Comment: Although the botframework docs provides no such details. neigther google.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/tree/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure, to understand how you can do this? There are some examples of implementations (using Azure storage and DocumentDb)

Comment: I've just tried to undestand by looking to those examples, but those two hides some important details about how to load the stored data correctly based on the botStoreType valeu you have received on the LoadAsync method. 
The Eric Dahlvang example show these details perfectly. It also show an example of the database schema you could adopt. But in anyway, thanks a lot Ezequiel Jadib for all the precisous help you have posted on all questions people have posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: a new blog post has just been published about how to implement IBotDataStore using sql server: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/26/Saving-State-Sql-Dotnet/

---

There is an SQL custom state client implementation here: [Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AzureSql](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AzureSql) It uses 'code first' and the EntityFramework.

Here's a script of the database:

```
USE [QuickSqlExampleBot]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SqlBotDataEntities]    Script Date: 7/25/2017 12:15:16 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SqlBotDataEntities](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BotStoreType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BotId] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ChannelId] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ConversationId] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Data] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [ETag] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ServiceUrl] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.SqlBotDataEntities] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [idxStoreChannelConversation]    Script Date: 7/25/2017 12:15:18 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idxStoreChannelConversation] ON [dbo].[SqlBotDataEntities]
(
    [BotStoreType] ASC,
    [ChannelId] ASC,
    [ConversationId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [idxStoreChannelConversationUser]    Script Date: 7/25/2017 12:15:18 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idxStoreChannelConversationUser] ON [dbo].[SqlBotDataEntities]
(
    [BotStoreType] ASC,
    [ChannelId] ASC,
    [ConversationId] ASC,
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [idxStoreChannelUser]    Script Date: 7/25/2017 12:15:18 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idxStoreChannelUser] ON [dbo].[SqlBotDataEntities]
(
    [BotStoreType] ASC,
    [ChannelId] ASC,
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SqlBotDataEntities] ADD  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [Timestamp]
GO
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric.

Comment: @EderCardoso I've edited this post.  Adding a link to a new blog post.